# don't show previously selected date in date-picker php

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, textbox

I don't want to see previously selected date in date-picker (or how to clear the text box) in php. 
It make difficult to select a different date or a new. Please see the attached screen shot.

Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTTfR.png)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( {
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: '-2d',
            endDate: '+0d',
            clearBtn : true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
});
```

You would then add it to your code like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: '-2d',
            endDate: '+0d',
            clearBtn : true,
        });
    });

    $('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
    });
 </script>
```